# Subtotal is not calculated correctly at order preview

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to create a chatbot with Dialogflow and Google Assistant along with Google Transactions API for enabling a user to order some items. For now my agent contains the following four intents:

- `Default Welcome Intent` (text response: Hello, do you want to buy a chocolate box?)
- `Default Fallback Intent`
- `Int3` (training phrase: Yes, I want, fulfilment: enabled webhook)
- `Int4` (event: `actions_intent_TRANSACTION_DECISION`, fulfilment: enabled webhook)

I am using Dialogflow Json instead of Node.js to connect my agent with Transactions API. I want to build a cart and an order for the user by using finally that the user meets the transaction requirements by using the `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION` action of Google actions. For this reason, following Google docs, when `Int3` is triggered I am using a webhook which connect Google Assistant my back-end which sends back the following json (to trigger `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION`) :

```
  {
    "fulfillmentText": "This is your order preview:",
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "isSsml": false,
            "noInputPrompts": [],
            "systemIntent": {
                "data": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionDecisionValueSpec",
                    "orderOptions": {
                        "requestDeliveryAddress": true
                    },
                    "paymentOptions": {
                        "actionProvidedOptions": {
                            "displayName": "VISA **** **** **** 3235",
                            "paymentType": "PAYMENT_CARD"
                        }
                    },
                    "proposedOrder": {
                        "cart": {
                            "lineItems": [
                                {
                                    "description": "Book",
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "name": "Book",
                                    "price": {
                                        "amount": {
                                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                                            "nanos": 0,
                                            "units": 31
                                        },
                                        "type": "ACTUAL"
                                    },
                                    "quantity": 2,
                                    "subLines": [],
                                    "type": "REGULAR"
                                }
                            ],
                            "merchant": {
                                "id": "Amazon",
                                "name": "Amazon"
                            },
                            "otherItems": []
                        },
                        "id": "<UNIQUE_ORDER_ID>",
                        "otherItems": [
                            {
                                "id": "Subtotal",
                                "name": "Subtotal",
                                "price": {
                                    "amount": {
                                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                                        "nanos": 0,
                                        "units": 62
                                    },
                                    "type": "ACTUAL"
                                },
                                "type": "SUBTOTAL"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "Delivery fees",
                                "name": "Delivery fees",
                                "price": {
                                    "amount": {
                                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                                        "nanos": 0,
                                        "units": 10
                                    },
                                    "type": "ACTUAL"
                                },
                                "type": "FEE"
                            }
                        ],
                        "totalPrice": {
                            "amount": {
                                "currencyCode": "USD",
                                "units": 72
                            },
                            "type": "ACTUAL"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "intent": "actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following errors on Google Assistant simulator:

```
MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data.transaction_decision_value_spec.proposed_order: subtotal price is not sum of regular lineItems. Expected-> Sum of line item price: units: 31 nanos: 0 currency: USD Actual-> Provided total price: units: 62 nanos: 0 currency: USD.

MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data.transaction_decision_value_spec.proposed_order: total price is not sum of lineItems and otherItems. Expected-> Sum of line item price: units: 42 nanos: 0 currency: USD Actual-> Provided total price: units: 72 nanos: 0 currency: USD.
```

**Why I am getting this error since I have specified that `"quantity": 2` in the respective `lineItem`?**

**It is very obvious that the subtotal should be `units: 62` since I have ordered `"quantity": 2` products of `units: 31` price each...**

The final order preview looks like this (this is borrowed from Google docs examples):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be in the error message: the API expects a each line item's price to be a sum of the total items in that line item instead of a quantity price (relevant error phrase: "Sum of line item price").  The corrected JSON should look something like this:

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "This is your order preview:",
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "isSsml": false,
      "noInputPrompts": [],
      "systemIntent": {
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionDecisionValueSpec",
          "orderOptions": {
            "requestDeliveryAddress": true
          },
          "paymentOptions": {
            "actionProvidedOptions": {
              "displayName": "VISA **** **** **** 3235",
              "paymentType": "PAYMENT_CARD"
            }
          },
          "proposedOrder": {
            "cart": {
              "lineItems": [
                {
                  "description": "Book",
                  "id": "1",
                  "name": "Book",
                  "price": {
                    "amount": {
                      "currencyCode": "USD",
                      "nanos": 0,
                      "units": 62
                    },
                    "type": "ACTUAL"
                  },
                  "quantity": 2,
                  "subLines": [],
                  "type": "REGULAR"
                }
              ],
              "merchant": {
                "id": "Amazon",
                "name": "Amazon"
              },
              "otherItems": []
            },
            "id": "<UNIQUE_ORDER_ID>",
            "otherItems": [
              {
                "id": "Subtotal",
                "name": "Subtotal",
                "price": {
                  "amount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "nanos": 0,
                    "units": 62
                  },
                  "type": "ACTUAL"
                },
                "type": "SUBTOTAL"
              },
              {
                "id": "Delivery fees",
                "name": "Delivery fees",
                "price": {
                  "amount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "nanos": 0,
                    "units": 10
                  },
                  "type": "ACTUAL"
                },
                "type": "FEE"
              }
            ],
            "totalPrice": {
              "amount": {
                "currencyCode": "USD",
                "units": 72
              },
              "type": "ACTUAL"
            }
          }
        },
        "intent": "actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @matthew. To be honest, this is what I implemented after I wrote this post. However, I expected that Google Assistant itself would calculate the total price for one item since I provide it the price of the individual item and the number of items ordered. Therefore, this is not an option/possiblity at Google Assistant? (If it is not then obviously your answer, which I also implemented, is the only possibility)